# ANTLR mismatched input error

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm writing a parser for my own language. I'm trying to parse the phrase

```
Number a is 10;
```

which is basically equivalent to `int a = 10;`.

It should match the `variable_def` rule. When I run it, I get the error

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'Number' expecting {<EOF>, 'while', ';', 'if', 'function', TYPE, 'global', 'room', ID}
line 1:9 mismatched input 'is' expecting '('
```

This is my grammar:

```
grammar Script;

@header {
package script;
}

// PARSER

program
:
    block EOF
;

block
:
    (
        statement
        | functionDecl
    )*
;

statement
:
    (variable_def
    | functionCall
    | ifStatement
    | forStatement
    | whileStatement) ';'
;

whileStatement
:
    'while' '(' expression ')' '{' (statement)* '}'
;

forStatement
:
;

ifStatement
:
    'if' '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}'
    (
        (
            'else' '{' statement* '}'
        )
        |
        (
            'else' ifStatement
        )
    )?
;

functionDecl
:
    'function' ID
    (
        '('
        (
            TYPE ID
        )?
        (
            ',' TYPE ID
        )* ')'
    )?
    (
        'returns' RETURN_TYPE
    )? '{' statement* '}'
;

functionCall
:
    ID '(' exprList? ')'
;

exprList
:
    expression
    (
        ',' expression
    )*
;

variable_def
:

    TYPE assignment
    | GLOBAL variable_def
    | ROOM variable_def
;

expression
:
    '-' expression # unaryMinusExpression
    | '!' expression # notExpression
    | expression '^' expression # powerExpression
    | expression '*' expression # multiplyExpression
    | expression '/' expression # divideExpression
    | expression '%' expression # modulusExpression
    | expression '+' expression # addExpression
    | expression '-' expression # subtractExpression
    | expression '>=' expression # gtEqExpression
    | expression '<=' expression # ltEqExpression
    | expression '>' expression # gtExpression
    | expression '<' expression # ltExpression
    | expression '==' expression # eqExpression
    | expression '!=' expression # notEqExpression
    | expression '&&' expression # andExpression
    | expression '||' expression # orExpression
    | expression IN expression # inExpression
    | NUMBER # numberExpression
    | BOOLEAN # boolExpression
    | functionCall # functionCallExpression
    | '(' expression ')' # expressionExpression
;

assignment
:
    ID ASSIGN expression
;

// LEXER

RETURN_TYPE
:
    TYPE
    | 'Nothing'
;

TYPE
:
    'Number'
    | 'String'
    | 'Anything'
    | 'Boolean'
    | 'Growable'? 'List' 'of' TYPE
;

GLOBAL
:
    'global'
;

ROOM
:
    'room'
;

ASSIGN
:
    'is'
    (
        'a'
        | 'an'
        | 'the'
    )?
;

EQUAL
:
    'is'?
    (
        'equal'
        (
            's'
            | 'to'
        )?
        | 'equivalent' 'to'?
        | 'the'? 'same' 'as'?
    )
;

IN
:
    'in'
;

BOOLEAN
:
    'true'
    | 'false'
;

NUMBER
:
    '-'? INT '.' INT EXP? // 1.35, 1.35E-9, 0.3, -4.5

    | '-'? '.' INT EXP? // -.35, .35e5

    | '-'? INT EXP // 1e10 -3e4

    | '-'? INT // -3, 45

;

fragment
EXP
:
    [Ee] [+\-]? INT
;

fragment
INT
:
    '0'
    | [1-9] [0-9]*
;

STRING
:
    '"'
    (
        ' ' .. '~'
    )* '"'
;

ID
:
    (
        'a' .. 'z'
        | 'A' .. 'Z'
        | '_'
    )
    (
        'a' .. 'z'
        | 'A' .. 'Z'
        | '0' .. '9'
        | '_'
    )*
;

fragment
JAVADOC_COMMENT
:
    '/*' .*? '*/'
;

fragment
LINE_COMMENT
:
    (
        '//'
        | '#'
    ) ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
;

COMMENT
:
    (
        LINE_COMMENT
        | JAVADOC_COMMENT
    ) -> skip
;

WS
:
    [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
;
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is because in your current grammar, the `TYPE` token will never be created because `RETURN_TYPE` matches a `TYPE` too and is defined before `TYPE` (and has therefor precedence over it).

Also, you're doing too much in the lexer. As soon as you start gluing words together in the lexer, it's a sign you should be making those rules parser rules instead.

And white spaces might be skipped by the lexer, but only from parser rules. Take your `ASSIGN` rule for example:

```
ASSIGN
 : 'is' ( 'a' | 'an' | 'the' )?
 ;
```

This rule will not match the string `"is a"` (a space between `"is"` and `"a"`), it will only match `"isa"`, `"isan"` and `"isthe"`. The solution: create a parser rule from it:

```
assign
 : 'is' ( 'a' | 'an' | 'the' )?
 ;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
assign
 : 'is' ( 'a' | 'an' | 'the' )?
 ;

IS : 'is';
A : 'a';
AN : 'an';
THE : 'the';

...

ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
```

This will cause the tokens `'is'`, `'a'`, `'an'` and `'the'` to never be matched as an `ID` token. So the following source will fail as a proper assignment:

```
Number a is 42;
```

because the `'a'` is tokenized as an `A` token, not an `ID`.

To work around this, you could add the following parser rule:

```
id
 : ( ID | A | AN | IS | THE | ... )
 ;
```

and use that rule in other parser rules instead of `ID`.

A quick demo would look like this:

```
grammar Script;

// PARSER

program
 : block EOF
 ;

block
 : ( statement | functionDecl )*
 ;

statement
 : ( variable_def
   | functionCall
   | ifStatement
   | forStatement
   | whileStatement
   )
   ';'
 ;

whileStatement
 : 'while' '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}'
 ;

forStatement
 :
 ;

ifStatement
 : 'if' '(' expression ')' '{' statement* '}'
   ( ( 'else' '{' statement* '}' ) | ( 'else' ifStatement ) )?
 ;

functionDecl
 : 'function' id ( '(' ( type id )? ( ',' type id )* ')' )?
   ( 'returns' return_type )? '{' statement* '}'
 ;

functionCall
 : id '(' exprList? ')'
 ;

exprList
 : expression ( ',' expression )*
 ;

variable_def
 : type assignment
 | GLOBAL variable_def
 | ROOM variable_def
 ;

expression
 : '-' expression             # unaryMinusExpression
 | '!' expression             # notExpression
 | expression '^' expression  # powerExpression
 | expression '*' expression  # multiplyExpression
 | expression '/' expression  # divideExpression
 | expression '%' expression  # modulusExpression
 | expression '+' expression  # addExpression
 | expression '-' expression  # subtractExpression
 | expression '>=' expression # gtEqExpression
 | expression '<=' expression # ltEqExpression
 | expression '>' expression  # gtExpression
 | expression '<' expression  # ltExpression
 | expression '==' expression # eqExpression
 | expression '!=' expression # notEqExpression
 | expression '&&' expression # andExpression
 | expression '||' expression # orExpression
 | expression IN expression   # inExpression
 | NUMBER                     # numberExpression
 | BOOLEAN                    # boolExpression
 | functionCall               # functionCallExpression
 | '(' expression ')'         # expressionExpression
 ;

assignment
 : id assign expression
 ;

return_type
 : type
 | 'Nothing'
 ;

type
 : TYPE
 | 'Growable'? 'List' OF TYPE
 ;

assign
 : 'is' ( A | AN | THE )?
 ;

equal
 : 'is'? ( EQUAL ( S
                 | TO
                 )?
         | EQUIVALENT TO?
         | THE? SAME AS?
         )
 ;

id
 : ( ID | OF | A | AN | EQUAL | S | EQUIVALENT | TO | THE | SAME | AS )
 ;

// LEXER

// Some keyword you might want to match as an identifier too:
OF : 'of';
A : 'a';
AN : 'an';
EQUAL : 'equal';
S : 's';
EQUIVALENT : 'equivalent';
TO : 'to';
THE : 'the';
SAME : 'same';
AS : 'as';

COMMENT
 : ( LINE_COMMENT | JAVADOC_COMMENT ) -> skip
 ;

WS
 : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
 ;

TYPE
 : 'Number'
 | 'String'
 | 'Anything'
 | 'Boolean'
 ;

GLOBAL
 : 'global'
 ;

ROOM
 : 'room'
 ;

IN
 : 'in'
 ;

BOOLEAN
 : 'true'
 | 'false'
 ;

NUMBER
 : '-'? INT '.' INT EXP? // 1.35, 1.35E-9, 0.3, -4.5
 | '-'? '.' INT EXP? // -.35, .35e5
 | '-'? INT EXP // 1e10 -3e4
 | '-'? INT // -3, 45
 ;

STRING
 : '"' .*? '"'
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

fragment EXP
 : [Ee] [+\-]? INT
 ;

fragment INT
 : '0'
 | [1-9] [0-9]*
 ;

fragment JAVADOC_COMMENT
 : '/*' .*? '*/'
 ;

fragment LINE_COMMENT
 : ( '//' | '#' ) ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The particular error occurs because in the lexer part of the grammar TYPE term clashes with RETURN_TYPE lexer term. There're other mistakes as well, but the problem showcase may be stripped down to just following:

```
grammar Script;

program
:
    block EOF
;

block
:
    (
       statement
     | functionDecl
    )*
;

statement
:
    (
      variable_def
    ) ';'
;

functionDecl
:
    'function' ID
    (
      'returns' RETURN_TYPE
    )?
    '{' statement* '}'
;

variable_def
:
    TYPE assignment
;

expression
:
    NUMBER # numberExpression
;

assignment
:
    ID ASSIGN expression
;

RETURN_TYPE
:
    TYPE
    | 'Nothing'
;

TYPE
:
    'Number'
;

ASSIGN
:
    'is'
    (
        'a'
      | 'an'
      | 'the'
    )?
;

NUMBER
:
    '-'? INT // -3, 45
;

fragment
INT
:
    '0'
  | [1-9] [0-9]*
;

ID
:
     (
        'a' .. 'z'
      | 'A' .. 'Z'
      | '_'
     )
     (
        'a' .. 'z'
      | 'A' .. 'Z'
      | '0' .. '9'
      | '_'
    )*
;

WS
:
    [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip
;
```

if `RETURN_TYPE` is converted into a *parser* rule, e.g `returnType`, then everything goes Ok (for this particular test, as I said your grammar contains other mistakes like this one). This demonstrates the basic princple regarding Antlr (and all other parser generators with lexer and parser separated) behaviour: *the lexer is always works in its own context*, it can't determine if a particular sequence of symbols is one term or another if both terms share the same sequence of characters. So you have two options: introduce *lexer* contexts (called [modes](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules#LexerRules-LexicalModes)) or leave on the lexer level only basic and unambiguous entities, and move everything else to parser.